# Got error while working with custom dialogbox in android

Tags: java, android

I am creating one custom dialogbox where i got some error while displaying it

code is:

```
@Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getBaseContext());
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.addexpense);
                    dialog.setTitle("Expense Entry");


                    Button cancle, done;  



                    done=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btndone);

               done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(final View v) {
                            dismissDialog(1);
                        }
                    });
               dialog.show();

                  }
                }); 




    }
```

Its Like there is a button and click event have to display a dialogbox. But I got error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException


ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):at com.nrp.Display $1.onClick(ViewExpense.java:196)
```

The layout.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
     android:orientation="vertical"> 

     <Button android:id="@+id/btndone" 
             android:text="done" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
     </Button> 
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Button is being created at runtime.

Comment: What is on line 196? `findViewById(int id)` can return null, is the NPE on that line?

Comment: its done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

Comment: @user2869524 so,  done = null )

Comment: no is at onclicklistener

Comment: @user2869524 can you show .xml code of layout and onCreate method of your DialogBox class?

Comment: no @Suvitruf it is a Button

Comment: @Suvitruf sure just a sec

Comment: your button is in the dialog xml and not in the main xml so you have to do v.findViewbyId or dialog.findViewbyId

Comment: thank you all for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your done and cancel button is in the `addexpense` layout and when you just call findViewById() return npe because your button not in main layout and if i right you must use `dialog.findViewById()` instead of `findViewById()`

Answer (score 0):

On line 196 you want to set a listener on a button. The button is identified by [findViewById(int id)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29). As mentioned in my comment to your question, [findViewById(int id)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29) can return null.

Please check the layout XML file(s) and ensure that the button is found.